# layerslider editor plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have used [layerslider for wordpress](http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/), and was about to integrate layerslider into another webapp of mine, but it seems that layerslider standalone completely lacks the editor part that naturally comes with it in the wordpress version, what's up with that?

I suppose I could write up my own editor, wouldn't be too complex... but I can't believe it hasn't been done already, especially since they got one in the package with the wordpress version.

Anyone know of any editor at all for the layerslider jquery plugin out there on the market?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially you should point out your requirements explicitely – "good" is a rather subjective criterium, and not really specific stand-alone – and you'd not expect us recommending "bad" ones, would you? ;)

Comment: There, I removed the word "good" and added a link. All I want to know if there exists any editor for the layerslider, apart from the wordpress-integrated one.

Comment: Thanks for the update (I've "integrated" your link for better readability). As that's not my area of expertise, I'll leave the rest for "better knowing members" :) Good luck!